# What are the fastest solutions to demo/try MS Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I would like to test Sharepoint. Since I'm short on time, I'm looking for fast solutions. It must be for Sharepoint 2007 or above.

I only have access to my PC wich runs with Windows XP Pro SP3.

The only thing I came up with is to install VirtualBox, install Windows as my guest and install Sharepoint. This seems like a lot of stuff to install and administer just to take a look at a product. Maybe I missed something? Any suggestions?

Comment: God help me for recycling an old joke, but I swear the first thing that popped into my head was "...at 9.8m/s^2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to try Microsoft SharePoint on an XP workstation is in their free TechNet Virtual Labs.  You can try this without any need for a Windows Server test box of your own.  Link:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb512933.aspx

From the linked page:

> Get first-hand deployment experience
>   through the Virtual Lab series. The
>   Microsoft Office SharePoint Server
>   2007, Windows SharePoint Services 3.0,
>   and Microsoft Office SharePoint Portal
>   Server 2003 virtual labs will teach
>   you about installation, organizing
>   content, managing user permissions,
>   creating Web Parts for custom tasks,
>   and much more.
>
> It's simple: no complex setup or
>   installation is required to try out
>   SharePoint Products and Technologies
>   running in the full-featured TechNet
>   Virtual Lab. You get a downloadable
>   manual and a 90-minute block of time
>   for each module. You can sign up for
>   additional 90-minute blocks any time.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest way I know is to use the MS VHD located here [SharePoint 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=67f93dcb-ada8-4db5-a47b-df17e14b2c74&displaylang=en)  Once you have that, you can use something like WinImage to convert to a  VMware image [Convert Image](http://ntpro.nl/blog/archives/194-Convert-Virtual-Disks-from-VHD-to-VMDK.html) and run VMware player, Server , etc. on your XP box.  You could download Hyper-V As mentioned in other reply) and avoid the conversion but I think the VMware route might be faster to deploy ( not faster to run)

Comment: Hyper-V is a Windows Server 2008 technology.  It cannot be downloaded and run on an XP box.

Comment: Sorry Was not suggesting running Hper-V on the XP box but creating a new 2008 system of some kind.  Hence my suggestioin to use VMware Server or similar.